# Accessing child class variables from its parent class

Tags: c++, object-oriented, design-patterns, comparative-review

## Requirements

The code should be able to call a parent method to read and modify child object variable that is referenced by a pointer inside the Child class. This code is to be run on an embedded environment, so memory and performance requirements must be addressed.

## Application

The proposed solutions allows a parent class to have access to the child class variables. If for an example we have a class `Player` that inherits classes `Stats` and `Events`. The class `Player` loads stats using methods from class `Stats`. Then when an event occurs it will trigger a method inside `Events` class which will read and modify stats from a variable that is declared in its child class `Player`.

## Solution 1

Using a virtual method in a parent class and implement it in a child class will allow it to be called in a parent class and in-turn be able to get the required object.

#### Example A. Using one parent class

```
#include <iostream>

class Life {
    public:
    int meaning;
    Life(){
        meaning = 42;
    }
};

class parentClassA {
    public:
        virtual Life* getLife();
        void printMeaningOfLife() {
            Life* A = this->getLife();
            std::cout << A->meaning << std::endl;
            A->meaning = 9001;
        }

};

class childClass : public parentClassA {
    public:
        Life* A;
        childClass() {
            A = new Life;
        }
        Life* getLife() {
            return this->A; 
        }
};

int main()
{
    childClass c;
    c.printMeaningOfLife();
    std::cout << c.A->meaning << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Example B. Using multiple parent classes

```
    #include <iostream>

class Life {
    public:
    int meaning;
    Life(){
        meaning = 42;
    }
};

class parentClassA {
    public:
        virtual Life* getLife()=0;
        void printMeaningOfLifeA() {
            Life* A = this->getLife();
            std::cout << A->meaning << std::endl;
            A->meaning = 9001;
        }

};

class parentClassB {
    public:
        virtual Life* getLife()=0;
        void printMeaningOfLifeB() {
            Life* A = this->getLife();
            std::cout << A->meaning << std::endl;
        }

};

class childClass : public parentClassA, public parentClassB {
        Life* A;
    public:
        childClass() {
            A = new Life;
        }
        Life* getLife() {
            return this->A; 
        }
};

int main()
{
    childClass c;
    c.printMeaningOfLifeA();
    c.printMeaningOfLifeB();

    return 0;
}
```

#### The good

- Does not create copies of the object
- Accessing the object requires only one function

#### The bad

- N/A

## Solution 2

Passing an object pointer by reference to a function that requires it.

```
#include <iostream>

class Life {
    public:
    int meaning;
    Life(){
        meaning = 42;
    }
};

class parentClassA {
    public:
        void printMeaningOfLife(Life*& A) {
            std::cout << A->meaning << std::endl;
            A->meaning = 9001;
        }

};

class childClass : public parentClassA {
    public:
        Life* A;
        childClass() {
            A = new Life;
        }
};

int main()
{
    childClass c;
    c.printMeaningOfLife(c.A);
    std::cout << c.A->meaning << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### The good

- Does not create copies of the object

#### The bad

- Requires that the pointer be passed on every method between the child class and the accessing location

## My conclusion

In my opinion and for my requirements I prefer the first solution. Reason being that I have 5 methods between object and accessing location which would make code readability and maintainability harder. Since the object is only referenced and not copied there should be minimal impact on memory.

## The questions

- Did I make any mistakes?
- Can this be improved?
- I could only think of these two solutions. Is there a different/better one?
- What are other good and bad sides of using these two solutions?
- Is having a requirement to access a child variable in a parent class a bad design all in itself?

## Edit

Since there were no answers I'm assuming that the code and my conclusion is valid. I have also edited the code to use pure virtual functions instead of *regular* ones to force implementation.

Comment: Is this actual code used in a project, or is it merely hypothetical?

Comment: This is the code that I have written to solve the problem that I currently face. If there are no problems with the proposed solutions to the requirements I will implement this into my current project.

Comment: Okay - What task does this code accomplish? Please tell us, and also make that the title of the question via [edit]. "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Please read [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @SamOnela Edits have been made. Unfortunately, my company prevents me to talk and publish code of developing projects so I can't tell what the actual project is and what this solves in it.